# Arduino issue: String to float adds two zeros instead of the correct integer

Tags: string, floating-point, arduino

Code snippet:

```
Serial.println(sensorString);  //so you can see the captured string
char carray[sensorString.length() + 1]; //determine size of the array
Serial.println(sizeof(carray));
sensorString.toCharArray(carray, sizeof(carray)); //put sensorString into an array
float sensorStringFloat = atoi(carray); //convert the array into an Integer

Serial.println(sensorStringFloat);
```

Serial.println(sensorStringFloat) prints out 5.00 instead of the correct float value of 5.33.  Why is that and how do I fix this issue?  I would eventually like to pass sensorStringFloat over to:

```
aJson.addNumberToObject(sensor, "ph", sensorStringFloat);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

atoi converts a numeral in ASCII to an integer. The comment on that line also says it converts to an integer. So you got an integer result, 5. To convert to floating-point, consider using atof. (Note that “f” stands for floating-point, not “float”. atof returns a double.)

Comment: Should I change the float in front of sensorStringFloat to double?  
EDIT:  
I tried both float and double and I get the same value.  I now ran into another slight  
issue:  
aJson.addNumberToObject(sensor, "ph", sensorStringFloat);  
  
returns: {"name":"SensorBoardOne","Sensor":{"ph":5.33000}}  
  
Is there any way to save up to two decimal places like how I would do println(someFloat, 2);?

Comment: You can use a float as long as it contains enough precision for your task. • I do not know what your second issue is; you show a return value but do not indicate what is wrong with it or what you expect instead. • I do not know what you mean by saving two decimal places. Once you have stored the value in a float, it is yours to do what you will with—save it, print it, calculate with it. Note that neither float nor double stores “decimal places”. The usual implementation is binary, not decimal; the float or double contains a 24- or 53-bit value multiplied by a power of 2 and a sign.

Comment: Understood.  The 'issue' is not technically an issue.  sensorStringFloat returns 5.33000.  Please note the ending 000s.  I should have asked a better question like, how can I truncate or trim the last three 000s? I would rather use 5.33 instead of 5.33000.  Also, the jSON string of {"name":"SensorBoardOne","Sensor":{"ph":5.33000}} will be sent to a c# application which reads/sends incoming/outgoing serial communication.

Comment: Formatting that sort of output is a separate issue, which I am not prepared to answer for the language and tools you are using. I suggest you ask a separate question for it. However, keep in mind that the float does not store 5.33; it stores something near 5.33, likely 0x1.551eb8p+2, which is 5.3299999237060546875. If you always want to format it with two decimal places, that is likely straightforward. But if you want to figure out how many trailing zeroes it has and remove them, that is a problem, since it is not 5.33 with trailing zeroes but is a different number.

Comment: Alright, formatting is all I would like to accomplish.  I do have a basic knowledge of floats after reading for a about an hour.  What I do not understand is why it returns a constant trailing three zeros at the end of the floats.  The sensor could return a 5.33 and 4.96 and etc. another time.  When I pass the float over to: {"name":"SensorBoardOne","Sensor":{"ph":4.96000}}  the trailing three zeros are there.  Are they appended at some point?  Thank you for your help. I will create another question for my formatting question.

Comment: I suspect the default format for printing is simply six significant digits or something similar.

Comment: I researched into the aJson.cpp file and found this line: //how much digits after . for float
#define FLOAT_PRECISION 5  I simply change the value from 5 to a 2 and the zeros are no longer trailing.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass another parameter which defines the format, in this case it is the number of digits after the floating point.

```
Serial.println(sensorString,2);
```

Comment: I visited arduino.cc and continued to further study println.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

`String temp = String (_float, 0);`

`say float x;`

convert to String using
`String _temp = String(x, 0);`

The second parameter 0... says i want no trailing zeros.

Caution: However this is only suitable for whole numbers.
This solution would not work for say... 1.24
You'll get just 1.